# Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'

Tags: node.js, angular, command-line-interface, mean.io

I am trying to run a MEAN project. When I run the following command in cmd:
ng build --watch

I get the following error:

[cannot find module '@angular/compiler/cli'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozjTw.jpg)

Here is some extra info:
[angular cli version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhhUq.jpg)

Comment: is `"@angular/compiler"` in your package.json? If not, just install it: `npm i @angular/compiler --save`

Comment: this saved me big time.. randomly stopped working after `cd` .. thanks @Brandon